# How do I represent tiles in XML?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, abstraction, papervision3d

So, I'm writing an AS3 program that tiles floor tiles. I want the user to be to be able to create their own floor schematic represented by different rectangles. It'll be drag-and-drop. They will lay out their schematic (which is composed of different size rectangular tiles) and drop colors/patterns onto them.

This schematic will then be tiled on a 3D plane to represent what the actual floor would look like.

I've got the 3D part working, drag-and-drop working, etc. What I'm missing is the floor schematic stuff. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out the best solution, but I can't QUITE get there.

Here are some examples (out of a WHOLE bunch of possible combinations) of how the floor schematics could look:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The different tiles within the schematic are the droppable regions. My problem: **How can represent these schematics in XML**? Don't worry about tiling, sizing, etc. I've got that all figured out already. I just literally do not know how I can represent a tile schematic in XML and draw it correctly with AS3. Any ideas?

Comment: In the case of non-rectangular schematics, it is not 100% obvious how they will fit together ... unless they ALWAYS form horizontal strips. These schemes could go diagonally when combined as well, for instance the second one ... please do clarify. BTW, why do you want to serialize this in XML? Are you already able to fill a floor based on such schematic?

Comment: As far as XML format ... at a high level you could pick a bounding box and for every cell specify color, and borders if any. For instance: "(0,0):<RGBVALUE1>,LRTD;(1,0):<RGBVALUE2>,LTD;..." <== This started to describe number two. Here LRTD = left,right,top,bottom. I realize that what I started to describe is not XML, but it can be turned into XML.

Comment: The non-rectangular schematics will fit together by row or by column. That means there could be horizontal offsets or vertical offsets in the tiling.

And, I need to be able to rebuild these schematics for future editing. Serializing as XML seemed like the best bet for Flash to me because it's web-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your tiles really boil down to layouts on a grid.  Given that, I would have the xml for the tile be comprised of a list of elements, each element would have properties for the row/column of the upper left square of the element, the row span and column span for that element, and the fill for that element.  Something like this:

```
<Tile>
    <Cell row="0" col="0" rowSpan="1" colSpan="4" fill="#a0a0a0"/>
    <Cell row="1" col="0" rowSpan="1" colSpan="4" fill="#b0b0b0"/>
    <Cell row="0" col="4" rowSpan="2" colSpan="2" fill="#c0c0c0"/>
    <Cell row="2" col="2" rowSpan="1" colSpan="4" fill="#a0a0a0"/>
    <Cell row="3" col="2" rowSpan="1" colSpan="4" fill="#b0b0b0"/>
    <Cell row="2" col="0" rowSpan="2" colSpan="2" fill="#c0c0c0"/>
</Tile>
```

The above would represent your first example (I made up the colors though).  Hope that helps.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine - preserves information about blocks, which can be helpful for editing. I was obsessed with borders for some reason. Anyhow, I will keep my answer as is; I do not think that it is terrible, just not great. However, DO USE XML header: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and look into generating an XML schema from a file just in case - those are two things I would add to the answer.

Comment: That's exactly how I would do it. Then in your app just have a static fromXML() method on your Tile object which returns a new tile based on those parameters. The only other thing I might add that might be useful in the XML above is "totalRows" and "totalCols" attributes on the <Tile> node itself, just so you can get a rough idea of the size without having to parse it all out.

Comment: I think this is a nice, simple solution. I never thought about implementing it similar to a standard HTML table. I like the simplicity here.

I would make the fill be rgba though. That way for the empty cells I could specify them as transparent.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, you might want to consider using the x, y, width, height values. That is the format that `flash.geom.Rectangle` and `flash.display.Graphics.drawRect()` use.

```
<tile x="20" y="20" width="400" height="200" pattern="1" />
<tile x="20" y="220" width="100" height="100" pattern="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not the best person at writing XML. For instance, `<Cell x="0" y="1" tile="no"/>` can be a pain, for it makes xsd schema more complicated - which is: if tile = no, it should not have children. If tile = yes, then it must have children. Also note that you need to rework `<RgbColor>LightGrey</RgbColor>`. Also note that I do not know what is the best trade-off between elements and attributes. Also note that I do not like having `<Cells>` as well as `<Cell>` - typo opportunity. However, I do not know a better way, but would like to find out what that might be. Also, perhaps this format is too verbose. Also, I did not include an xsd schema, but you can get started with it here: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=xsd+schema+generator&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Also inspired by another answer, you might want to define pattern colors separately and then refer to them ... can be error-prone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TileSchematics name="Blah" comment="This starts to describe second one.">
  <BoundingBox>
    <Width>8</Width>
    <Height>3</Height>
    <StackHorizontally>yes</StackHorizontally>
    <StackVertically>no</StackVertically>
  </BoundingBox>
  <Cells>
    <Cell x="0" y="0" tile="yes">
      <RgbColor>LightGrey</RgbColor>
      <Border>
        <Right>yes</Right>
        <Left>yes</Left>
        <Top>yes</Top>
        <Bottom>yes</Bottom>
      </Border>
    </Cell>
    ...
    <Cell x="0" y="1" tile="no"/>
    ...
  </Cells>
</TileSchematics>
```

Comment: I like this solution too, but it does seem a little too verbose. You did solve the border issue though. Couldn't really wrap my head around that. Wish I could accept both of these for different reasons! :)

Answer (score -1):

why XML? why not just serialize it using AMF3? or if you need something human readable, [JSON](http://json.org/) should do it. JSON has exactly the same object semantics as ECMA-script, being a subset of ECMA-script, while XML doesn't, which makes working with XML quite annoying.

representation of the first schematic as object structure:

```
[
    {"x":0, "y":0, "width":100, "height":25, "pattern":0 },
    {"x":0, "y":25, "width":100, "height":25, "pattern":1 },
    {"x":100, "y":0, "width": 50, "height":50, "pattern":2 },
    {"x":50, "y":50, "width":100, "height":25, "pattern":0 },
    {"x":50, "y":75, "width":100, "height":25, "pattern":1 },   
    {"x":0, "y":50, "width": 50, "height":50, "pattern":2 }
]
//this is both valid JSON and ActionScript, although in ActionScript, you would
//typically use identifiers instead of strings for property names
```

You can use the [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) for [serialization](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/adobe/serialization/json).

greetz
back2dos

Comment: XML was asked for, so give him XML.

Comment: @Matt W: "Serializing as XML seemed like the best bet for Flash to me because it's web-based". With that being the reason for choosing XML, I feel obliged to point out alternatives.

Comment: I didn't know that you could serialize JSON with Actionscript. I'll consider adding that to future projects, but for this project, I've already done A LOT of work with XML. It's pretty much a requirement without a lot of refactoring. Great idea for the future though!